# Nbconvert export interactive figure - Jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook, widget, nbconvert

I'm trying to export a jupyter notebook using nbconvert that maintains the interactive figure. The figure works fine in the notebook but it returns to a static image after using Nbconvert.

I've tried the following commands to maintain the interactive figure

```
!jupyter nbconvert Untitled.ipynb --to webpdf --template classic
!jupyter nbconvert --to webpdf --allow-chromium-download Untitled.ipynb
!jupyter nbconvert --to html --execute Untitled.ipynb
!jupyter nbconvert --ExecutePreprocessor.store_widget_state=False --to html --execute Untitled.ipynb


%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ipywidgets import interact

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

def update(w = 1.0):
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(w * x))
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

interact(update);

plt.show()
```

notebook:

[image]

Export:

[image]